# Set featured image to archive.php

Tags: custom-post-types, php, post-thumbnails, custom-post-type-archives

At the moment I create a new page, set a featured image and link a certain CPT template to show all those CPT's (by using a query) with the featured image on top. However, this is in my opinion the wrong way to do this because each time I create a new CPT I'll have to create a new template. My page types now look like "default, cases, products, clients, ..." which is not the purpose of a template.

I tried using archive-CPT.php which will automatically loop through the correct CPT but the problem is that I can't use a featured image anymore. I could, but I want to change/remove/add the image via Wordpress like I do with pages...

How would I be able to achieve this the right way?

EDIT:
archive-clients.php

```
<?php
  while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  $header = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
    $title = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'page_title', true);
    $subtitle = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'page_subtitle', true);
?>
<header class="page-header about-header" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $header; ?>)">
  <h1 class="page-hero-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
  <h2 class="page-hero-subtitle"><?php echo $subtitle; ?></h2>
</header>

<?php
  endwhile; 
  while( have_posts() ) 

: the_post();
?>

<div class="row clients">
  <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Why you can't use a featured image anymore? It has nothing to do with where the posts are being shown. Please provide your code to be clearer what are you doing

Comment: If I use `archive-CPT.php` (not using it as a template, but generated by WP) then I'm not able to add an featured image. I want to avoid having `Cases archive` or `Product archive` in my page templates because nothing else can use this..

Comment: `archive-{post_type}.php` is not generated by WP. The responsibility lies on the Theme. Why don't you share your code?

Comment: Have added minimised code example. This was my `page template` first but have changed it to `archive-client.php` which means I can't reach the page meta anymore..

Comment: Can you post the code you use to create the custom post type.

Comment: I'm using Toolset plugin to create CPT

Comment: silly question maybe, have you enabled Featured Images in the plugin for the CPT?

Comment: I might have not been clear enough, but I want one featured image for the archive page. Not the featured image per CPT

Comment: When you say "Not the featured image per CPT" you mean not posts featured image?

Comment: Oh you mean the featured image of the Page?? Not the featured image of the each post ? You should be more clearer.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The featured image of the page. I had a custom template page with an image and that custom template loaded all the CPT with a query. However, I find that messy and I wanted to use archive-{CPT}.php which will loop automatically through the right CPT but this means I can't set a featured image anymore.

Comment: With all due respect but it clearly states in the first sentence though :)

Comment: :) You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the right way to do this is to create theme options. Create a field asking the desired image for the clients post type archive.

Comment: True, that's a solution but it puts me off because I'll have to add more fields in the future when there are more CPT's archive pages..

Comment: You can dynamically create the theme option fields looping through all your CPT's

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll have to check that out then. Thanks!

Comment: The answer provided here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32164479/1287548 will help you to achieve it.